# Gathering Post Values on Form Error in the Play Framework using Scala

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, frameworks

I am still pretty new to the play framework and I am currently trying to get the values on post when the there is an error. I need these values to display the information based on the IDs that being passed as hidden values.

Here is my updateOperatorsPost controller method:

```
  val updateOpForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "op_id" -> longNumber(min = 0),
      "ad_id" -> longNumber(min = 0),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText(maxLength = 50, minLength = 2),
      "status" -> nonEmptyText(maxLength = 255, minLength = 2),
      "city" -> nonEmptyText(maxLength = 50, minLength = 2),
      "stateName" -> nonEmptyText(maxLength = 20, minLength = 2),
      "street1" -> nonEmptyText(maxLength = 50, minLength = 2),
      "street2" -> text(maxLength = 50),
      "zip" -> longNumber(min = 1)
    )
  )
  def updateOperatorPost = Action{implicit request =>
    updateOpForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors=>BadRequest(html.updateOperator(errors, Operator(0, 0, "A", "B"), Address(0, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))),
      {case (op_id, ad_id, name, status, city, stateName, street1, street2, zip) =>
        models.Operators.update(op_id, ad_id, name, status, city, stateName, street1, street2, zip.toString)
        Ok(html.index(models.Operators.retrieveAllOperators()))
      }
    )
  }
```

Here is my form:

```
@(updateOpForm: Form[(Long, Long, String, String, String, String, String, String, Long)], op:Operator, ad:Address)
@import helper._
@main("Update Operator"){
<a style="font-size: 25px; text-decoration: none" href="/"><- Home</a> <br />
<form action="/updateOperatorPost" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="op_id" value="@op.id"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ad_id" value="@ad.id" />

    @helper.input(updateOpForm("name")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@op.name"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("status")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@op.status"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    <h2>Address</h2>
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("city")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@ad.city"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("stateName")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@ad.stateName"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("street1")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@ad.street1"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("street2")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@ad.street2"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    @helper.input(updateOpForm("zip")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@ad.zip"@toHtmlArgs(args)>
    }
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
}
```

As you can see I am passing some made up objects just to see the form when there is an error, I would like to pull in the data based on the ids that are hidden in the form. Is this possible? I hope I made this clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bit of code that helped me

```
 val op_id = (request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("op_id")(0)).toLong
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the value directory from the request body

```
def updateOperatorPost = Action{implicit request =>
  updateOpForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors=> {
      val opId = (request.body \ "op_id") asOpt[String] getOrElse "op_id was not included in the request"
      // Do something with opId
      BadRequest(html.updateOperator(errors, Operator(0, 0, "A", "B"), Address(0, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))
    },
    {case (op_id, ad_id, name, status, city, stateName, street1, street2, zip) =>
      models.Operators.update(op_id, ad_id, name, status, city, stateName, street1, street2, zip.toString)
      Ok(html.index(models.Operators.retrieveAllOperators()))
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: @JamesLittle You should mark this as the answer if it works for you

Comment: I get the error `value \ is not a member of play.api.mvc.AnyContent`, am I missing an import?